# HorizontalScrollView doesn't scroll after adding View to its layout

Tags: android, scroll, gallery, horizontalscrollview, infinite

I create infinite picture's gallery.
My idea is removing first or last child View from HorizontalScrollView, when it scroll too far.
Here's my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mygallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In "onTouch" callback I determine, which direction scrolls View. If it turns to the left, I've got to remove first child View with picture, add another one to the end of HorizontalScrollView and scroll it to the second picture, because after deleting first picture my View shows third(last) picture. So first picture will be on the left, last picture will be to the right.

```
Log.i(TAG, "Moving to the left");
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0); //moving to the start of scroller to see the first picture
removeLastPicture(); //removing last picture
prependPicture(); //prepending picture
scrollView.scrollTo(pictureWidth, 0); //I've got to scroll my scroller to the center
```

Last string doesn't work. HorizontalScrollView show first picture and doesn't scroll to the center picture. What do I wrong?

And by the way, may be there's some more interesting desicion for my gallery? I want change only one picture by one scroll.

Comment: **"I want change only one picture by one scroll."** Do you want to have more than one picture on the screen at the same time or only one at a time? You could try using `ViewPager` if you only want one at a time.

Comment: Yes, this is better decision for my task. But, how can I implement continious ViewPager, without "position"? I want to load last picture if I reached beginning and go to the left further, or load first picture if I reached end.

Comment: Keep count of the pictures. If there are 10 pictures (for example) then each time the `ViewPager` moves from the right then add 1 to the count - if it is 11 then set the count back to 1 and display the required picture. Do the same when paging from the left but subtract 1 from the count each time.